Number of valid password entries
After 5 consecutive failed login attempts using email/password with firebase authentication, I cannot log in even if I enter an email/password that allows me to log in for the 6th time. However, if I wait a minute or so, I can log in by entering the email/password that allows me to log in.
I was looking for specifications regarding the limitation on the number of times a password can be validly entered, but I can't find any. Can you please tell me about the specifications?
The log output is shown here.

Error:Uncaught(in prromise):FirebaseError:Firebase:Access to this account has been temporarily disabled due to many failed login attempts.You can immediately restore it by resetting your password or you can try again later.(auth/too-many-requests).

enter image description here

Answer below. This may not be the most helpful as this is pretty much an XY problem, so I recommend updating your question (or posting a new one) with the actual goal of what you're trying to accomplish with this knowledge.

Firebase Authentication indeed limits how often a user can try to sign in in a certain interval. For email/password logins that number has been 5 for some time now, but it's intentionally not documented as it may be changed without notice when needed (as has happened for SMS based sign-in in recent years).
